# Handle concurrent requests in a not atomic findOneAndUpdate (with upsert) with transaction (in mongoose)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency

I have a post from front-end ,with ajax, that it sends a task name to the backend.
If the task name is new I add it to the collection otherwise I don't add.
If the task already exists I'm returning a 422 status code that may be isn't the proper status code but this is another story.
I'm in Node and I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose

```
  const createTask = async (req, res) => {

  let resQuery = await taskModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: req.body.name },
    { $setOnInsert: { name: req.body.name } },
    {
      new: true,
      upsert: true,
      includeResultMetadata: true,
      sanitizeFilter: true,
    }
  );

  //updateExisting is false if the document was already present
  if (resQuery.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting === true) {
    res.status(422).json({ success:false , data: "Task already exists" });
  } else {
    const { name, completed } = resQuery.value;
    res.status(201).json({ name, completed });
  }
};
```

It works like a charm. My concern is that if I have multiple client requests I could end with 2 or more task with the same name because `findOneAndUpdate` isn't atomic when I use the `upsert` option.
Then I'm using a transaction in this way:

```
const createTask = async (req, res) => {
  let resQuery;
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  try {
    await session.startTransaction();

    resQuery = await taskModel
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: req.body.name },
        { $setOnInsert: { name: req.body.name } },
        {
          new: true,
          upsert: true,
          includeResultMetadata: true,
          sanitizeFilter: true,
        }
      )
      .session(session);

    if (resQuery.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting) {
      throw new ErrorRequest(STATUS_CODE.BAD_REQUEST, "User already exists");
    }

    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    const { name, completed } = resQuery.value;
    res.status(201).json({ name, completed });
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    //Here I could call next(err) to handle all error in the same place
    res.status(422).json({ error: "Task already exists", data: req.body });
  }

  
};
```

Is it right my consideration about multiple concurrent requests? And is it good my workaround with transitions to handle this situation?

Comment: If you have a unique index on the filter, upsert will insert only one document

Comment: Can you explain more deep?  What do you mean with "unique index on the filter"?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-with-unique-indexes

Comment: The best practice is to use  `unique` on the field `name` , ok.  Nevertheless I would know if with my approach about concurrency requests there is the need to use transactions and if I have used them in the properly way.